# Sharedpreferences first startup, handling all values being null initially. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

First time a user starts an app, all SharedPreferences values are null.

If I set a color based on a sharedpreference value, it will crash before choosing the color in my settings.

What is the better way of these alternatives, are there other alternatives?

**1**. use `color: sp.getint != null : Color(sp.getint) : Colors.white`  everywhere SharedPreferences is accessed

**2**.
run something like this on startup

```
Future<void> setupSharedPreferences() async {
  if (sharedPreferences.getInt("color") == null) {
    await sharedPreferences.setInt("color", Colors.white.value);
  }
}
```

on startup?

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: The 2nd approach is fine with me and i like it better - there will be just one place in your code that checks and in inits default settings

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the shared preference in a separate layer and each function has a default value

```
class SharedPreferenceManager {
     final SharedPreference sp = SharedPreference();

     int getColor() {
         return sp.getInt("color") ?? Colors.white.value;
     }

     String getName() {
         return sp.getString("name") ?? "New User";
     }
}
```

this way you have all the default values in one file and you wouldn't have to await this on app startup since it will return the default value only when needed